# Node + Mongo : findOne OK but find().forEach DONT

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typeerror

my problem seems to be linked to the asynchronous aspect of node, but I can't understand why.

This code WORKS :

```
      expertsArray = ["expert1", "expert2"];
      db.collection("users").findOne({first_name: expertsArray[0]}, function(err, expert) {
        console.log(expert.userid);
        });
      });
```

This code BUGS :

```
      expertsArray = ["expert1", "expert2"];
      db.collection("users").find({ first_name: {$in: expertsArray} }, function(err, experts) {
        experts.forEach(function(err, expert) {
          console.log(expert.userid);
          });
        });
      });
```

In the second case, experts exists and is an [Object object], but the error is :

> error: [FATAL] An unhandled exception occured in your bot TypeError:
>   Cannot read property 'userid' of null

I also tried to put the first code into a FOR loop, but the same  bug appears...
Anyone could help me understand ? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: How can it be object and null at the same time... maybe it's a Schrödinger's variable.

Comment: Sorry for the typo : experts exists but expert do not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters in your `forEach` are wrong.

According to [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), the arguments are:

```
currentValue, index
```

But you have

```
err, expert
```

So try instead:

```
experts.forEach(function(expert, expertIndex) {
  console.log(expert.userid);
  });
});
```

Comment: You're the best ! ;) Thank you very much

Comment: I shoud have mixed up with the each() function :cursor.each(function(err, item) {